# trying to get property of non object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM i-register where contact = '".$contact"';  
$result = $con -> query($sql);  
$count = $result -> num_rows;
```

I am gettin the "trying to get property of non object on the 3rd line of the code I above mentioned." when I test the table variables by echo method its posting. but data's are not registering in database.

help me out with this one.

Comment: Can you please show your full code, because it seems there is some problem in connection codding. So please show us full code.

Comment: because you don't select num_rows in your SQL query ? (Also, i don't see quotes around the query string)

Comment: what do you means by the above comment @Moppo

Comment: Executing the query fails for whatever reason. No connection, syntax error or other error. Anyway, querying fails for that reason and returns false, and then you are trying to read `false`->num_rows.  Please use the various error-functions to read error information about what went wrong. There is no way to tell for us.

Comment: i used `echo $count;`  

but it didn't get printed. its a registraion page and data's are not posting

Comment: Can you please post your complete code?

Answer (score 0):

Your query fails to execute, resulting in invalid result. Thus you cannot get num rows from invalid result.

Use this as your first line:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM i-register where contact = '.($contact+0);
```

to ensure it compares always with a number.

Comment: why are you adding zero to $contact?